# Auditory receptive field mapping

Tags: sound

The [Wikipedia page on sound localisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_localization) states:

> Localization accuracy is 1 degree for sources in front of the listener
>   and 15 degrees for sources to the sides. Humans can discern interaural
>   time differences of 10 microseconds or less.

However, I can't find any more detailed information on localisation accuracy.

What I'm after is a plot of accuracy (Y) against azimuth (X).

Can anyone get me one step towards this information?

π

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate book on the topic is probably [http://www.amazon.com/Spatial-Hearing-Revised-Psychophysics-Localization/dp/0262024136](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262024136) . It's a bit dated but contains and excellent review of the main psycho-acoustic research on spatial hearing.

It is a very complicated topic. For example azimuth and elevation perception work completely different and hence azimuth resolution is quite a bit better than elevation resolution. The actually resolution (or jnd for just noticeable difference) depends heavily on the actual and the properties of the signal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of factors at play when it comes to localization of sound.  The primary factors are known as Interaural Intensity Difference (IID) and [Interaural Time Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaural_time_difference) (ITD).  In addition to those factors, the brain infers additional localization information from spectral cues encoded by the outer ear, or pinna.

All of these factors together form what is know as a Head-Related Transfer Function (HRTF).  Because of varying head shapes, head sizes, hairstyles (believe it or not) and ear shape and placement, each person's HRTF is unique.  As a result, the way that each person's brain infers localization information from auditory cues is also unique.  For this reason, any data that you may see about localization accuracy is almost certainly a statistical value, rather than an exact measurement.

If acoustical wave propagation was the only factor, it would be easy to generate a plot like you are talking about.  The problem is that our brains play a large role in the process.  For example, your brain has more neurons dedicated to localization of sounds in front of you than to your sides.  A google search for "ITD IID" returns a number of very informative tutorials and lecture notes that might help to understand the various phenomena at play in sound localization.

Having said all of that, you might be able to achieve a very rough estimation by simply plotting ITD as a function of azimuth angle.  That would probably be the most tractable starting point.

There is also an online database of Head-Related Impulse Responses (HRIR) available here:  http://recherche.ircam.fr/equipes/salles/listen/download.html  These HRIRs are measured by inserting [tiny microphones](http://recherche.ircam.fr/equipes/salles/listen/system_protocol.html) into the ear canals of about fifty test subjects and playing a sound stimulus from predetermined locations all around the head.  These impulse responses are essentially measuring the HRTF of each of the individual test subjects.

Hopefully you can find something that will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword is "minimum audible angle" -- throwing this into Google gives results.

For example, from [this page](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~briolle/9thISH.pdf), I got:

[image]

Also from [here](https://fedora.kug.ac.at/fedora/get/o:6537/bdef:Content/get), this:
[image]